# Dynamic Sitemap Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm trying to get dynamic_sitemaps gem to work with my site, but the readme is very technical and a bit over my head at the moment.

I'm running into errors when trying to generate the sitemap for this bit of code.

```
# You can have multiple sitemaps like the above – just make sure their names are different.

# Automatically link to all pages using the routes specified
# using "resources :pages" in config/routes.rb. This will also
# automatically set <lastmod> to the date and time in page.updated_at:
#
sitemap_for :offers
```

It's returning the below error

> ArgumentError: The collection given to `sitemap_for` must respond to
>   find_each. This is for performance. Use `Model.scoped` to get an ActiveRecord relation that responds to find_each.

I'm looking to have the sitemap contain all my offer posts etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model's name is Offer, try

```
sitemap_for Offer.all
```

(note: #scoped is deprecated, so #all seems to be the better option going forward)

Comment: Worked bloody perfectly - Thanks Brian!